# How do I make the selected layout display for all MarketPress pages?

Tags: plugins, themes

I've set up a WordPress site and installed MarketPress. It works fine overall and the `/store/` page is correctly displaying my selected template/layout.

However, all subpages such as `/store/products`, `/store/cart`, `/store/categories` etc. are not using the template/layout that I chose, but rather some default. Maybe this is because they are "virtual" pages that MP itself are handling.

Question is: How do I tell MarketPress to use my chosen template/layout for all of MarketPress´ pages?

I've tried a solution that I found [here](http://buildersnippets.com/how-to-assign-a-layout-to-any-marketpress-page-in-builder/), but it doesn't work for me. It could be a solution connected to some other product or plugin that the author has but not me.

Comment: Are you aware of the [MarketPress Template Hierarchy](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/the-easy-guide-to-theming-marketpress/)?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that I can bypass the admin interface by copying my chosen template (in the drop-down) code into five other php files, but that feels really unflexible and doesn't honor the drop-down select box in MarketPress' settings interface... I feel that such a hack would counterfeit the purpose of buying a pre-coded eCommerce plugin in the first place? And it would also make life hard for editors, of course